# Is this a general structure for constructs?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, universal-algebra, big-picture

Here a construct is a category where the objects are sets and the morphisms are structure preserving functions. Common examples are groups, graphs and topological spaces. As far as I can see there is a very general structure for all constructs:

A simple $F$-*construct* is a set and a binary relation $(X,\mathcal R)$ such that 
$\mathcal R\subset F(X)\times X$. The functor $F$ characterize the primary structure that determines the conditions on the morphisms and there could be secondary axioms on 
$\mathcal R$ separating categories from each other. More general constructs can be obtained by combining simple constructs.

For example, if $F(X)=X\times X$, then
$(X,\mathcal R)$ could be anything from categories
$(X=\text{Mor}(\underline C)$ with 
$((\alpha,\beta),\gamma)\in\mathcal R \iff \beta\alpha=\gamma)$ to groups when $\mathcal R$ is an associative function etc.

Non algebraic examples are topological spaces

$F(X)=\mathcal P(X)$ (power set) with $\mathcal (A,x)\in \mathcal R\iff x\in \bar A$

> What I'm looking for is possible counterexamples, known and newly
>   found constructs, that doesn't seems to fit in to the pattern.

---

As Tobias Kildetoft pointed out in a comment a relation is a very general approach $-$ and that is intentional. But $F$-constructs is about a normal form for all constructs as defined above and given in this normal form there is a general rule that determine the condition for a function to be a morphism.

A morphism is a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ satisfying the relation:

$(1)\quad\; (\phi,\psi)\in F(f)\Rightarrow\left[(\phi,x)\in\mathcal R^F_X\Rightarrow(\psi,f(x))\in\mathcal R^F_Y\right]$.

The meaning with the construction of the relation is demonstrated by the diagram: 
$\require{cancel}$
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    F(X) @>F(f)>> F(Y)\\
    @V \mathcal R_X^F VV\xcancel{\#} @VV\mathcal R_Y^F V\\
    X @>>f> Y
    \end{CD}

The upper row gives a condition on $f$ on the lower row, together with the relations, and the connection is given by $(1)$. (The diagram commutes if the $\mathcal R$:s are functions and $F(f)$ is a function or a anti-function.

> Of course, if someone find a counterexample of this condition, I would
>   be interested to know that too.

Examples of how $(1)$ works could be find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/171248/lehs).

I really don't understand the resistance against the question. *The method works*, and it is not easy to find *adequate* counterexamples.

Comment: Your definition of a construct does not seem to really pose any restriction to an arbitrary category. Is there some requirement that the arrows actually be maps of the sets?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: The condition is the relation, a sort of normal form. And yes, the arrows should be functions.

Comment: As the last time... Please try to be more rigorous when you write things. "A construct is a category where the objects are sets": everything in (standard) mathematics is sets. Based on your comments, do you mean to say that your category is equipped with a forgetful (= faithful) functor to $\mathsf{Set}$? Is $F$ a functor $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$? Etc.

Comment: @Lehs: You have already the same question a couple of times on math.SE and I had already given you counterexamples (sheaves for example), and indicated that there are tons and tons of counterexamples, and that therefore your "universal approach" does not make much sense.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: I have asked a *similar* question on MO. Are sheaves categories where sets are objects an structural functions are morphisms?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: Isn't a construct a category where the objects are sets (not every object is a set) and functions are the morphisms? The functor is from **Set** to **Rel**, but so far I have only found constructs where the functor maps functions to functions or anti-functions.

Comment: I am not aware of any standard meaning for the word "construct" (and nlab doesn't have a page named "construct" so I doubt one exists). So... you tell me? What is a construct, precisely?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi:"The following constructs; i.e., categories of structured sets and structure-preserving functions between them" (Abstract and concrete categories, Adámek et al.) See also [Wikipedia]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category#Relative_concreteness

Comment: @NajibIdrissim, this is a standard term; it just means a $\mathbf{Set}$-concrete category.

Comment: Lehs, I think you will find most constructs of coalgebras do not fit this pattern. Its a cool idea though. Does it really give the right notion of morphism for e.g. topological spaces, uniform spaces etc.? If so, I think that's kind of a big deal.

Comment: @goblin: thanks for the first positive feedback! I will see if I can grasp the concept of co-algebras. Are they structures on sets and are the morphisms functions? If they are counterexamples I'll have to reformulate, but that wouldn't increase the interest I guess... It does work for topological spaces, absolutely, but I don't remember if I tested the morphisms for uniform spaces rigorously.

Comment: @Lehs, you're welcome. I don't know much about coalgebras, but [here's](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coalgebra+for+an+endofunctor) a link to get you started. Don't worry too much about the resistance; most great ideas were resisted initially. Anyway, the important thing is not to get 100% of all kinds of mathematical structures ever considered. The important thing is whether it always gets the morphisms right. So I think you should work out, in detail, what the morphisms are in a large variety of cases. If your method consistently gets the right answer, then consider publishing an article.

Comment: @goblin: I'll try to make clear how it works with some crucial examples and leave a link in the Q. But as I would like to be sure that it become understandable it could take a while. I will kiss your feet sometime!